# storing varying array types in oracle and importing using csv files into array types

Tags: postgresql, oracle, sqldatatypes

How to store array types in oracle database. Is there any datatypes something like character varying[] type as in postgres, if i want to store the mobile numbers is there any simple way to store the array type.

I tried creating type as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ARRAY_TYPE 
AS VARRAY(10) OF varchar2(12);
```

But how should i import the array data in csv file containing column with array information as column {xxxx,yyyy} to oracle in array_type column in oracle.

Is there any simple way that will map the character varying [] types from postgres to oracle so that it is easy to import to and fro ?

Comment: By far the easiest option would be to build a standard relational data model where there is a `person` table and a child table `person_phone` that has one row for each phone number.  Otherwise, you're going to find that each database engine has a very, very different implementation of this sort of thing that is going to make moving data back and forth as well as porting queries and DML vastly more challenging.

Comment: ok fine thank you.